# Adding Roles To A member With A command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

okay so basically i tried to make a command that when i say .ar Admin @user
it give the user Admin or what ever the role name i mentioned after .ar but it makes me lose brain cells it took me so long plus my bot prefix didnt work because of the same problem so i bypass it by add the prefix my self in each command i need help and thanks in advance

i literally tried a lot of thing from arrow function to A normal code but the normal code only give the role to the new members (guildmembers)

```
`bot.on('message', message => {
  let userToModify = message.mentions.members.first();

  if (message.content.startsWith(".ar Admin" + userToModify)){
    userToModify.addRole('Admin');
}

});`
```

Well Like i said before whenever i declare a var or string and then go to
.startwith("random command" + Var) it just never worked i tried doing
let prefix : "!"
and then .startwith(prefix + "command") but it never worked i had to add the prefix manually without using + and i dont want to do the same with adding roles

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Define the role by grabbing it from the first argument in the message's content, and define the member how you did. Check if they exist.

When command is used, the role must be before the @mentioned user.

```js
bot.on("message", message => {

        const prefix = '!'; // just an example, change to whatever you want

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return; // ignores all messages that don't start with the prefix

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g) // creates an array of arguments for each word after the command
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase(); // this makes the command cASe iNseNsiTiVE

    if (cmd === 'addroll' || cmd === 'ar') { // can use 'addrole', or 'ar' to run command

        let roleToAdd = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === `${args[0]}`); // grab the role from the first argument
        let userToModify = message.mentions.members.first(); // grabs the mentioned user

        if (roleToAdd === null) {// if role doesn't exist(aka = null)
            return message.reply(`I couldn't find the ${args[0]} role.`);
        }
        if (userToModify === undefined) {// if noone is mentioned after the role
            return message.reply('You must `@mention` a user!');
        }

        userToModify.addRole(roleToAdd)// add the role
        return message.reply(`${userToModify} has been given the ${roleToAdd} role.`)



        // more code
    }
});
```

Tried and tested.

Comment: OMG it Really Worked Even With The Prefix OMG I Am So pleased btw i should have known that if i made the if statement into "!" the prefix should work like you did thank you again bro

Comment: I would suggest switching over to a command handler though, makes everything a lot cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: I don't know how to make command handler if you Can help me with basics of it will be pleased

Comment: @hokageminato there are a lot of tutorials on youtube, I made mine with this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUOb9_aAk7U